# Why docker run works but docker-compose for the same image does not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I try to run `rails new testapp` app with docker.
When I run it with `run -dp 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd):/app" testapp` it works fine, but when I try to run it with `docker-compose up` I get:

```
web_1  | Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
testapp_web_1 exited with code 10
```

Any idea why?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
```

Comment: it looks like you want `.:/app` under volumes.

Comment: yep, thanks for help, don't know how I put there ./app :)